# A simple understanding of the two-slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

According to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2408), there's no consistent treatment of the two-slit experiment:

> It is true that the usual textbook discussions of the two-slit experiment are riddled with ambiguities and omissions; and this is for the reason that a consistent, quantum-mechanical treatment of the two-slit experiment does not, to our knowledge, exist.

But would the following be a good rough approximation? At the slits, the particle is in a state $\phi = |slit 1\rangle + |slit 2\rangle$ (in the momentum basis). We get the interference patterns because we're measuring it in a non-commuting basis (position).

Comment: this is a more complicated set up but it starts with setting up a two slit wavefunction http://motls.blogspot.com/2017/03/interference-patterns-of-two-entangled.html

Comment: Thanks. He writes:$\psi = |L\rangle + |R\rangle$ . My question is: $|L\rangle$ and $|R\rangle$ are eigenstates of *which observable*? Position, right? If so, then my explanation above is wrong.

Comment: he is talking about straight trajectories, so he is in the position space.